# Keeping track of Navigation Controllers farther down the stack

Tags: ios, ipad, ios4

I have an iPhone app that I'm building that has the following seutp.

- AppDelegate creates a Navigation Controller and sets it's root controller to a MainController
- MainController creates a TabBarController
  and adds 5 TableViewControllers to it

When a user clicks a row in the Table I want to push it's view onto the Navigation controller. However, it's navigationController attribute is not set, I would need to access the MainController. I can get around this  by creating a property on the TableViewController and passing down the reference to the Navigation controller, but this feels dirty, especially if I would have to keep passing it down with more and more sub controllers. There has to be a better way.

I should note that I'm not using IB on the project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not access it from the app delegate?

This should work anywhere in your code.

```
-(id)mainController
{
     return [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] rootViewController];
}
```